# Unable to Connect to connect to Oracle 12c with SID But Service Name Works

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Database.  The database is hosted in a local virtual machine.

I can connect just fine **with Service Name:** `...@localhost:1521/orcl`
**However with SID:** `...@localhost:1521:cdb1` does not work.

Currently when I try and connect I get: `ORA-01017: Invalid username/password; logon denied`

**NOTE:**

- I'm using the ***EXACT SAME*** username and password for both login   - attempts.
- I can successfully connect to the **SID** with the 
  *system* user.

Answer (score 0):

Your service name is orcl - connection works.

Then you try a different database, 'cdb1', and the same user/password don't work.

Those are different databases, probably.

You're in a multitenant environment. You should always use the SERVICE name when connecting to a 12c instance. SID in a multitenant will always take you to the container database. The pluggables running in the container will only be reachable by their service name.

Comment: I thought SID was supposed to be more specific than service name.  I have some Java Code that will be targetting 11g. However the Dev environment I'm working against is 12c.  I'm reluctant to change from SID to service based unless I absolutelty have to. Is this maybe a configuration change on my Oracle DB, to make sure each instance has a unique SID?

Comment: if you're doing dev work in 12 and your app is going to be running in 11 - that's going to be a problem

change your dev env to 11. and read the 12c docs re: service vs sid in a multitenant environment